# How to use azure-functions-core-tools behind corporate proxy

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to setup a PoC for creating Azure Functions in our corporate setup.
Creating the function app, and generally using the Azure CLI, works fine.

I have the proxy settings stored in http_proxy and https_proxy.

When using `azure-functions-core-tools` I receive a "407 Proxy Authentication required" Error on `func azure functionapp publish <appname>`

Is there a way to

- Debug the actual error response? (To rule out other reasons than the auth failure)
- explicitly set the `azure-functions-core-tools` to use an authenticated proxy e.g. via http_proxy?

I have tried setting `--verbose` but it does not seem to be supported.

Versions:

- Azure CLI: 2.0.59
- azure-functions-core-tools: 3.0.3284

Comment: You might have better chances in posting your question directly to the github repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: Seems like it is not the #1 priority unfortunately... 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/915
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1336
-> Still interested in ideas for a solution

Comment: well, the probably best solution is anyway to not deploy from your machine directly (assuming thats what you are trying to do). Use a proper CI/CD pipeline

Comment: @silent of course most environments would be deployed by CI/CD. Still proper dev experience should come with the ability to deploy to Sandbox/Dev environments.

Comment: If your corporate network is via VPN then get off the VPN, deploy your stuff, get back on VPN. Given it's a PoC that should be acceptable. All you need are AZ creds that allows you access to your Func App in cloud.

Comment: The goal of the poc is to determine how to get it to work within the network. Turning off the vpn will only result in no internet at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after some research I found [this response on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1888#issuecomment-607398089).
So, simply add these environment variables either to your system or to your `local.settings.json` file:

```
    "http_proxy": "http://mycorporateproxy.com:mycorporateport",
    "https_proxy": "http://mycorporateproxy.com:mycorporateport",
    "no_proxy": "localhost,127.0.0.1",
    "HTTP_PROXY": "http://mycorporateproxy.com:mycorporateport",
    "HTTPS_PROXY": "http://mycorporateproxy.com:mycorporateport",
    "NO_PROXY": "localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

That approach worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. Our proxy is authenticated and it seems to have trouble parsing the proxy connection string with username and password.

Comment: Have you tried to pass username and password to the proxy URL? e.g.

`http://<username>:<password>@<mycorporateproxy.com>:<mycorporateport>`

N.B. Make sure you have encoded special characters (`!`,`@`,`-`, etc.) in your password, you can use some online tools for that, e.g. this 
- https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: The azure cli or function core tools seems to misinterpret the @ and use the username/password as host and port if you specify it like this

Comment: Can you show me the example of your URL? Just a pattern, so you can replace any letters and numbers to a fake values

Comment: exactly the same pattern you just commented before: `http://<username>:<password>@<mycorporateproxy.com>:<mycorporateport>`

Comment: I mean username and password, does it include any non alpha-numeric characters? If so, you will need to replace them with URL encoded values, so if you have something like this `http://bob@google.com:strongPas!@mycorporateproxy.com:8080` it should be changed to `http://bob%40google.com:strongPas%21@mycorporateproxy.com:8080`

Comment: Ah sorry, misunderstood. I am already using the proxy settings with other tools and it works fine. The problem is not related to encoding issues. Also tried a password without special character, same problem

Comment: Ok, I noticed that it doesn't work for me if I remove `HTTP_PROXY` from my system environment variables

Comment: @Abaddon666 I would configure CNTLM or PX( https://github.com/genotrance/px) as local proxy server to avoid using passwords in  plaintext