# "407 Proxy Authentication Required" at Azure Function with emulated Storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-407, azurite

I try to make a time-triggered function in Visual Studio 2022, while doing this at the debugging the following error occurs:

```
[2022-06-27T07:47:03.127Z] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
[2022-06-27T07:47:03.129Z] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2022-06-27T07:47:03.129Z] Status: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required)
```

My local.settings.json looks the following:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

I also tried to add our local company Proxy to this setting bs setting the values of HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY but they are skipped since already configured in Environment Variables:

```
Skipping 'http_proxy' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'https_proxy' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'HTTP_PROXY' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'HTTPS_PROXY' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'NO_PROXY' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
```

Also Azurite is up and running on Ports 10000-10002 as the Console says:

```
FunctionApp1: Azurite Blob service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10000
FunctionApp1: Azurite Blob service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10000
FunctionApp1: Azurite Queue service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10001
FunctionApp1: Azurite Queue service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10001
FunctionApp1: Azurite Table service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10002
FunctionApp1: Azurite Table service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10002
```

Do you have any idea why this could happen, or what I should configure?

Comment: Try including all the settings (`local.settings.json`) given in this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67675290) and check once which includes key-value pairs like both Upper Case and Lower case of http_proxy and https_proxy along with no_proxy setting and also encode the characters if username and password are present in the proxy values.

Comment: Hi, I already found this, but it didn't work for me, it just ignored this settings:
`Skipping 'http_proxy' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'https_proxy' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'HTTP_PROXY' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'HTTPS_PROXY' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'NO_PROXY' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.`

Comment: Could you provide the code how you're accessing the local environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the message from the console, it appears that the http_proxy variable is already set in the environment variables in windows. Could you please check the path/url of the http_proxy and other variables in the environment variables window and make sure they are correct?

Access env variable in windows : https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Please let me know the outcome. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).